# Homogeneous equations with shared solution

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(M),(N)$ be two homogenous equations with 4 unknowns over $\Bbb R$.

Also, $ (1,2,3,4)$ and $(5,6,7,8)$ are solutions of $(M)$. $(4,3,2,1)$ is a solution of $(N)$.

Is there a shared solution between the two equations other than the trivial one ?

$\_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ \_ $

What I tried was:

$ (M):= \ \alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2 x_2+\alpha_3 x_3+\alpha_4 x_4=0 $

Then equalize both solutions of $(M)$ (because both equal 0):
$ \alpha_1+2\alpha_2 +3\alpha_3 +4\alpha_4=5\alpha_1+6\alpha_2 +7\alpha_3 +8\alpha_4 $

$4\alpha_1+4\alpha_2+4\alpha_3+4\alpha_4=0  $

$\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3+\alpha_4=0  $

From here I'm not really sure how to continue or even if I'm on the right track so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  you subtracted the first solution for $M$ from the second.  What happens is you subtract it again?

Comment: You mean: (4,4,4,4)-(5,6,7,8)=(-1,-2,-3,-4) OR (1,1,1,1)-(5,6,7,8)=(-4,-5,-6,-7) ? You're saying I can get to the solution of N from the solutions of M ?

Comment: Now add in some $(1,1,1,1)$'s to one of these...

Comment: Magic! Thanks!!